# How to access files outside of root directory in localhost?

Tags: javascript, python, html, url, directory

I have some common angular files one-level outside of my local site's root directory, like so:

```
-- angular.js
-- angular-sanitize.js
-- root
   |-- index.html
   |-- client.js
   |-- style.css
```

I want to link the files to `index.html`, so I tried something like (for angular.js),

- `../angular.js`
- `/G:/User/angular.js`
- `./../angular.js`

but none of them worked out. Why it is so and how to do it correctly?

**EDIT:** I'm using a Python server.

Comment: you could host your common files on a seperate server. This would work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot access files outside your htdocs folder because your server considers that to be the root folder. Hence has no parent folder. Or in basic terms, your apache server is only available in your htdocs folder. So you might have to move your files there or give a link to them online.

Conclusion: There is no way you can do that.

Or maybe you have to edit your `httpd.conf` file

Comment: I'm sorry! I forgot to include that I'm using a python server. Also, this means that I've to copy the _framework scripts_ in each folder, since I don't want to include cdn's. That's memory-demanding!

Comment: Btw, Welcome to stackoverflow! LimitlessClaver :)

Comment: I guess there was a similar query on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53970696/python-flask-static-folder-outside-root-directory

Check that out, it might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You must put the whole project within the server folder (htpdocs, http etc) then inside the project you may use links like - ../somescript.js to access files outside of your folder but not the server space